# Regular expression in template literals. Escaping characters

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, string-literals, template-literals

I am trying to use graphql-constraint-directive with apollo graphql server.
I need to put reg. expression in a template literal like this

```
const typeDefs =   gql`
input ClaimInput {
  id: String!
  date: String!
  phone: String @constraint(pattern: "^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$")
  email: String
  invoice: String
  doctorId: String
  therapy: [TherapyInput]
  files: [FileInput]
}
`
```

It didn't work for me. No match. Regular expression is correct. The sample works with this one *@constraint(pattern: "^[0-9a-zA-Z]*$")*.

So I realized that something wrong with *^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$*  in my template literal typeDefs.

I've checked in Node REPL:

```
> v = `^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$`
'^05d([-]{0,1})d{7}$'
> v = `^05\\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$`
'^05\\d([-]{0,1})d{7}$'
```

When I put \d  \ is ignored.
When I put \\d I have \\d. Not what I need.

How to deal with this situation?

**Editing:**
I think the problem is in **gql from 'apollo-server'**

When I've changed to:

```
const typeDefs = gql`

input ClaimInput {
  id: String!
  date: String!
  phone: String @constraint(pattern: "^05\\d([-]{0,1})\\d{7}$")
  email: String
  invoice: String
  doctorId: String
  therapy: [TherapyInput]
  files: [FileInput]
}
`
```

I've got an error:
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Invalid character escape sequence: \d.

When I've changed to

```
const typeDefsRaw = String.raw`
input ClaimInput {
  id: String!
  date: String!
  phone: String @constraint(pattern: "^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$")
  email: String
  invoice: String
  doctorId: String
  therapy: [TherapyInput]
  files: [FileInput]
}
`
const typeDefs = gql`${typeDefsRaw}`;
```

I've got the same error:
GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Invalid character escape sequence: \d.

Comment: Anyway, I've submitted a new issue in apollo-serve repo. https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/issues/4727.  If any update I let everybody know

Comment: why not to graphql-constraint-directive ? how it's apollo-server related ? why apollo-server has to fix some extension issue?

Comment: @xadm GraphQLError: Syntax Error: Invalid character escape sequence: \d. The problem in gql

Comment: then it should be https://github.com/apollographql/graphql-tag ?

Comment: '// Names must match /^[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*$/ as per graphql-js' >> https://github.com/confuser/graphql-constraint-directive/blob/master/index.js#L10  ... then any escape not supported ... you must restrict it at resolver level

Comment: on resolver you can use any regex you need

Comment: That's exactly what I did - \d  === [0-9]. However I'm afraid there will be cases when I have to use \ . I could use resolver as well but what's the point of graphql-constraint-directive

Comment: for simple use cases? more advanced needs resolver

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224490/discussion-between-albert-lyubarsky-and-xadm).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.raw`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw):

```js
v = String.raw`^05\d([-]{0,1})\d{7}$`
```

`\\d` is also correct if you don't/can't use `String.raw`. It only displays as `\\d` since the preview in the REPL has to be a copy-pastable string. If you `console.log(v)` you will see only one backslash.

Comment: Thank for a quick answer. I am going to check it now.

Comment: You answer it correct. Thank you. However it doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`\d` means a digit, so a workaround would be to use `[0-9]` instead of `\d`.